# Show that $T$ is Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem that came up as I was learning Hermitian/skew-Hermitian transformations:

---

Let $T: V\rightarrow E$ be a linear transformation where $V$ is a subspace of a complex Euclidean space $E$ and define a scalar-valued function $Q$ on $V$ such that $\forall x \in V$:

$$Q(x) = (T(x),x)$$

where $()$ denotes inner product.

Show that if $Q(x)$ is real for all $x$, then $T$ is Hermitian i.e. $(T(x),y) = (x,T(y))$

---

**My work:**

Since $Q(x)$ is real, we know that $\forall x \in V$, $Q(x) = \overline{Q(x)}$

$Q(x+ty) = (T(x)+tT(y), x+ty) = Q(x) + t(T(y),x) + \bar{t}(T(x),y) + t\bar{t}Q(y)$

$\overline{Q(x+ty)} = (x+ty, T(x)+tT(y)) = (x,T(x)) + t(y,T(x)) + \bar{t}t\bar{t}(x,T(y))+(y,T(y)) = Q(x) + t(y,T(x)) + \bar{t}(x,T(y)) + t\bar{t}Q(y)$

Putting the two equations together, I get: $$t(T(y),x) + \bar{t}(T(x),y) = t(y,T(x)) + \bar{t}(x,T(y))$$

I feel like this is close, but I'm not sure how to continue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't fully convinced by comparing coefficients. Here's another way:

Substituting $i$ and $1$ for $t$ in the equation gets:

$(T(y),x)+(T(x),y) = (y,T(x))+(x,T(y))$ and

$i(T(y),x)+(-i)(T(x),y) = i(y,T(x))+(-i)(x,T(y))$ or

$(T(y),x)+(-1)(T(x),y) = (y,T(x))+(-1)(x,T(y))$

Adding, you get:

$(T(y),x) = (x,T(y))$

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are done by comparing coefficents in the last equation.

Comment: Well your equation tells you, that $$t(T(y),x)+ \bar{t}(T(x),y) =t(y,T(x))+ \bar{t}(x,T(y))$$ so let's rephrase this: $$ ta+\bar{t}b = tc+\bar{t}d $$ from this follows $ a=c $ and $b=d$ because their coefficents in the sum are the same. And this yields exactly that $T$ is Hermitian.